# Specific proof of irreducibility of $X^2-3$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

I am working on the following exercise:

> Prove that there exist no $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $(a+b\sqrt{2})^2=3$. Conclude from this that $X^2-3$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[X]$.

Proving the first part took me no effort. I am completely stuck on the second part, however. That is, how does the second part follow from the first part? Any help or hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Well, how could it reduce...?

Comment: Hello, I am not in doubt about wether the polynomial is reducible or not, but about how irreducibility follows from the first part of the question. Actually, let me add this to my question, to make it more clear what I'm stuck on.

Comment: Again, how could it reduce?  The linear term has to go away, so it has to reduce by $(x-\alpha)(x+\alpha)=x^2-3$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.  Now look at the constant term and solve for $\alpha$.

Comment: I see, I think I get it now; in the case you described, $\alpha$ has to be equal to some $a+b\sqrt{2}$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$, which square should be equal tho $3$, a thing that is shown to be impossible in the first part of the exercise. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

How do you characterize that a polynomial has root $\alpha$  in terms of divisibility?

Comment: Do you mean that, if a polynomial P(X) has a root a, then it can be written as Q(X)(X-a) for some other polynomial Q(X), in other words being reducible? What about the converse; if a polynomial has no roots, does that automatically mean it is irreducible?

Comment: For your first question: yes (this is a result from high school). The converse is true only for polynomials of degree $2$ or $3$, because if they're not irreducible, they must have a linear factor.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Assume by contradiction that 
$$X^2-3=(ax+b)(cx+d) $$
for some $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$.

Show that you have either 
$$a\sqrt{3}+b=0 \mbox{ or } \\
c\sqrt{3}+d=0 \\
$$

Deduce that $\sqrt{3}$ is a ratio of elements in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ and hence an element in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$.